# Using GROUP BY and HAVING on a LEFT JOIN table where there is no records stored

Tags: mysql, left-join, having

There is a table where payment data towards invoices are recorded.  I am using SUM to count the total payment amount towards the invoice.  I only want to show invoices that have not been paid.  So I created a WHERE clause using GROUP BY and HAVING to only show records that have records sum'ing to less than the total invoice amount.

But...If there are no records to find in the Payments table, the system cannot find any invoices to display.  Anyone else had this issue?  I'm open to changing to a different format but I need it to function the same way where it only finds invoices with payment amounts of less than the total invoice amount due OR no payments at all.

```
$query = "
SELECT o.id, o.user_id,o.invoice_number,o.total,SUM(p.payment_amount) as paid 
FROM User_Order_Details as o 
LEFT JOIN User_Payments as p ON (p.user_id = o.user_id AND p.order_id = o.id) 
WHERE o.user_id = '1' AND o.invoice_number != '' 
GROUP BY p.order_id 
HAVING SUM(p.payment_amount) < o.total 
ORDER BY o.ship_date DESC
");
```

Comment: It works perfectly as long as there is at least 1 record of payment for the order/invoice in the User_Payments table.  If there are no records for that order/invoice, then it cant find any invoices to pull records for.

Comment: I had to have HAVING in order to use SUM after the where clause.  In order to have HAVING, I had to use GROUP BY.  The issue is GROUP BY and HAVING with no records to pull

Comment: Then make your query from `User_Payments`, this will allow you to get all necessary records.

Comment: Start selecting from `User_Payments` and then join the `User_Order_Details` and if there are no records associated with `User_Order_Details` for this payment return `null`.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco - But wouldnt that return the same issue.  If there isnt a payment listed for that order/invoice in User_Payments, it wouldnt return any of the other order/invoices.  So if the customer hadn't made a payment at all, the invoice wouldnt show.  But I need it to.Anything that has payments up to the total amount AND orders with no payments need to show

Comment: unless I create a UNION and create two separate queries in one.  I didn't think about that one.  I'd prefer not to do that if I don't have to though.

Comment: But like i understand, it may be some records, which does not belong to any `User_Payments`, correct? so the `User_Order_Details` may have records when `User_Payments` is empty.

Comment: I need ALL invoices FROM User_Order_Details to show if it meets at least 1 of the following... 1) No payments have been recorded in User_Payments    2) There is payments in User_Payments and the SUM of the payments are LESS than the Invoice/Order Total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when no payments have been made, `SUM(p.payment_amount)` is `NULL`, and comparing `NULL` to anything always results in `FALSE` (hence `HAVING SUM(p.payment_amount) < o.total` doesn't return those rows). So you need to use `COALESCE` to convert that value into `0`, which can then be successfully compared. Note that MySQL allows you to use aliases in the `HAVING` clause, so you can just use `paid` there:

```
$query = "
SELECT o.id, o.user_id,o.invoice_number,o.total, COALESCE(SUM(p.payment_amount),0) as paid 
FROM User_Order_Details as o 
LEFT JOIN User_Payments as p ON (p.user_id = o.user_id AND p.order_id = o.id) 
WHERE o.user_id = '1' AND o.invoice_number != '' 
GROUP BY p.order_id 
HAVING paid < o.total 
ORDER BY o.ship_date DESC
");
```

Comment: PERFECT!!!! Didn't think about that.  Figured it would be a simple fix.  Thank you!!  It is now working